# Publish Multiple APK with different android version

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

Is it possible Publish 2 apk for different android version?

I using cordova to build to apps and I need to use crosswalk to build when android version below v4.4.

Higher than v4.4 android just use normal build.

Comment: I don't know much about cordova, but why can't you use a support library to accommodate to both versions? Or execute different code based on the android version?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can publish multiple APKs to the Play Store.

Each APK must be signed with the same key and must use a different version code. The version that supports a higher minimum SDK version must have the higher version code.

By have two different APKs with differed `minSdkVersion`s defined, users will receive whichever version has the highest support API level.

For full documentation regarding this feature, read the [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) documentation.